# Graphi API - Send a message to a channel on behalf of the application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

## The goal

Send messages to Microsoft Teams channels on behalf of an [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2?view=graph-rest-1.0)

## The (proposed?) flow

Have a Microsoft teams end user browse to a URL which grants the application access to the user's Team using [OAuth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0)

## What I've tried #1

I have created an Application as per the guide above:

1. Instruct the user to browse to

> ```
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<my_client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Channel.ReadBasic.All%20https://graph.microsoft.com/Team.ReadBasic.All%20https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.ReadWrite.All%20offline_access&state=12345
> ```

2. The user authorizes access for the application, and in return I get a temporary code.
3. I exchange the code using my client_id and client_secret for an access token:

   ```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token 

   grant_type authorization_code
   code <code>
   client_id <client_id>
   client_secret <client_secret
   ```
4. I get the access_token from the response. So far so good!

When I try sending a message to a channel, the message appears to be coming **from the user who authorized the app, and not from the app itself**.

## What I've tried #2

I've tried changing the `grant_type` to `client_credentials`, as per the documentation:

> Some apps call Microsoft Graph with their own identity and not on behalf of a user. In many cases, these apps are background services or daemons that run on a server without the presence of a signed-in user

So I assumed maybe now I will be able to send the message on behalf of the application, But I am having difficulties setting the necessary permissions when exchanging the temporary code with an access token. The scope I'm setting is `https://graph.microsoft.com/Channel.ReadBasic.All` and I'm getting the following error:

> AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope
> https://graph.microsoft.com/Channel.ReadBasic.All is not valid. Client
> credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to
> the resource identifier (application ID URI).

I've tried setting it to `api://<api_id>/.default` with no luck as well.

As a side note, the same process took me [30 minutes for Slack](https://api.slack.com/authentication/basics).

## Update #1

It's possible to achieve the goal using [Incoming webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet).
I am still trying to figure out if there's a way to create these webhooks programmatically (so far no luck in finding a REST API for this)

Comment: You will need Application permission instead of Delegated permission, if you are using grant_type = client_credentials

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting number of concepts confused, which is understandable because there a ton of concepts at play, and they each have their own complexity. Essentially:

1. You need to have an "App" registration in Azure AD. It can either be in your own Azure AD (e.g. ISV scenario) or in the same Azure AD as the user (e.g. internal enterprise app).
2. In either case, because you are wanting to post -as- the application (and not delegated on behalf of the user), there needs to be a consent for your application to take actions, and this consent needs to be granted, for you scenario, by a Tenant Administrator. See more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal
3. Once that's done, you can authenticate against the Microsoft Graph using your Azure App ID and App Secret. For this, you'd use the SDK relative to your platform (e.g. JS, dotnet, etc.).

The above will cover a lot of the underlying murkiness for you. You should not need to have either your code, or your user, visit login.microsoftonline.com, for instance.

It's quite a broad question, so hard to answer shortly like this - hopefully the above will steer you in the right direction.

With regards the actual sending of the message, you can see this Graph endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http albeit that there's lots of confusing messaging there about migration/not migration.

Another option, if you're wanting to send a message like this, is to rather explore creating a Bot. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots and specifically Proactive Messaging as well at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet - if you go that route, there's a bit of a learning curve, but then you have the power of Bots available to you for all kinds of things in Teams.

Your best option though is probably just a webhook, if you're wanting to just send a simple message. You've said in your Update that it's not working though - please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for that, Hilton! While this flow allows one to create an application, I still haven't found a way to send a message on behalf of it

Comment: Many thanks for the update. Yes, I was just looking at incoming webhooks this morning and did a small POC - this is exactly what I'm looking for. The issue here is that it seems like it's impossible to create incoming webhooks using a REST API - the only way I found to create them is manually through the MSTEAMS app (by going to the channel, clicking on 'Connectors' and select 'Configure' under 'Incoming webhooks')

Comment: I'm not sure what your overall scenario is that you need this, but there are some options here. First off, I think you can package your webhook as a Connector, to make it more easily reusable across multiple teams+channels. Alternatively, the bot option is also reusable. In both cases though, the standard is for the user to choose to install them into that location - are you wanting them pre-installed, or automatically installed? That's also possible, but requires more steps of course